# Only read the last character in a .txt file

Tags: python, processing

I am creating a program using processing that read txt file and send the result to the arduino.
I can get it to send string and keep update, but as soon as I try to just send the last char it won't work... Can anyone help me with this? Basically I need to read the last char from a txt file and send it as char through serial to arduino, python or processing both will work!

*Here is my code [ Processing ]

```
import processing.serial.*;
import java.io.*;

int mySwitch=0;
int counter=0;
String [] subtext;
Serial myPort;
   
void setup(){
   //Create a switch that will control the frequency of text file reads.
   //When mySwitch=1, the program is setup to read the text file.
   //This is turned off when mySwitch = 0
   mySwitch=1;
 
   //Open the serial port for communication with the Arduino
   //Make sure the COM port is correct
   myPort = new Serial(this, "COM4", 9600);
   myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
}

void draw() {
   if (mySwitch>0){
       /*The readData function can be found later in the code. This is the call to read a CSV file on the computer hard-drive. */
       readData("G:/Personal/control.txt");
 
       /*The following switch prevents continuous reading of the text file, until   we are ready to read the file again. */
       mySwitch=0;
   }

   /*Only send new data. This IF statement will allow new data to be sent to the arduino. */
   if(counter<subtext.length){
       /* Write the next number to the Serial port and send it to the Arduino There will be a delay of half a second before the command is sent to turn the LED off : myPort.write('0'); */
       myPort.write(subtext[counter]);
       delay(500);
       myPort.write('0');
       delay(100);

       //Increment the counter so that the next number is sent to the arduino.
       counter++;
   } else{
       //If the text file has run out of numbers, then read the text file again in 5 seconds.
       delay(5000);
       mySwitch=1;
   }
} 


/* The following function will read from a CSV or TXT file */
void readData(String myFileName){
 
 File file=new File(myFileName);
 BufferedReader br=null;
 
 try{
   br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
   String text=null;
 
   /* keep reading each line until you get to the end of the file */
 while((text=br.readLine())!=null){
   * Spilt each line up into bits and pieces using a comma as a separator */

   subtext = splitTokens(text,",");
 }
 }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
 }catch(IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
 }finally{
     try {
        if (br != null){
           br.close();
        }
     } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

And this is the data that i am dealing with

> [19:54:57] [Server thread/INFO]: [@] b
>
> [19:54:57] [Server thread/INFO]: [@] a
>
> [19:54:57] [Server thread/INFO]: [@] b
>
> [19:54:57] [Server thread/INFO]: [@] a
>
> [19:54:58] [Server thread/INFO]: [@] b
>
> [19:54:58] [Server thread/INFO]: [@] a
>
> [19:54:59] [Server thread/INFO]: [@] b
>
> [20:30:23] [Server thread/INFO]: [@] a
>
> [20:30:24] [Server thread/INFO]: [@] b
>
> [21:07:34] [Server thread/INFO]: [@] a
>
> [21:07:35] [Server thread/INFO]: [@] b

- The only value that I really care is a / b
- And this file will consistently update in this format

Comment: Show us your code and a sample file with the char

Comment: Added the code and the data that I am dealing with :)

Answer (score 12):

Reading the last character from a file:

```py
with open(filename, 'rb+') as f:
    f.seek(f.tell()-1,2)    # f.seek(0,2) is legal for last char in both python 2 and 3 though
    print f.read()
```

**For Python 3**
To make it more generic say we want to read second last (can be any though) char of the file without turning on the binary mode:

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.seek(0, 2)
    # seek to end of file; f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END) is legal

    f.seek(f.tell() - 2, 0)
    # seek to the second last char of file;
    # while f.seek(f.tell()-2, os.SEEK_SET) is legal,
    # f.seek(-2, 0) will throw an error.

    print(f.read())
```

Seek is a file object handling comment

`file.seek(offset,position)`

1. `offset`: How many characters you need (i.e. 1 means one character)
2. `position`: Tell where your file read/write operation should start .

   - 0 means starting of file
   - 1 means current position of file  read/write cursor
   - 2 means end of file

`f.seek(f.tell()-1,2)` means go to the end of file and traverse back one element

`print f.read()` prints the value obtained from the seek command

Comment: import os
    with open('G:\Personal\control.txt' , 'rb+') as f:
     f.seek(-1,2)
     print f.read(1)
Like this?

Comment: The explanation of `offset` parameter can be reworded a bit. Currently it leaves the impression that `offset` determines how many bytes are read with the next call to `read`, which is only true in this very specific context (because we are reading everything to the end of the file). Also, `2` can be replaced with os.SEEK_END to make it more readable, and `+` mode is not actually needed, as the file is not modified, only read.

Comment: Note that this reads in binary mode which not work well for all use cases. If you are in an append+read (a+) mode and need to use strings, then [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51131242/1526703)

Comment: To make the code more explicit you can use built-in constant [`os.SEEK_END`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.SEEK_END) instead of `2` when calling `seek()`

Comment: thanks this was the only solution that worked properly for me. I had to fish out 100 lines of good code from a 20,000,000 line ipynb file that had printed a ludicrously large error messages

Comment: Do note: this is Undefined Behavior.

SEEK_SET or 0: seek from the start of the stream (the default); offset must either be a number returned by TextIOBase.tell(), or zero. Any other offset value produces undefined behaviour.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek

Answer (score 6):

Answer of Stefan is simple and kind of works, but does not account for text files with:

- **UTF-8 encoding** containing non-English characters (which is the default encoding for text files in Python 3)
- one **newline character at the end of the file** (which is the default in Linux editors like `vim` or `gedit`)

If the text file contains non-English characters, neither of the answers provided so far would work.

What follows in an example that solves both problems.

```
import os


def get_last_utf8_char(filename, ignore_newlines=True):
    """
    Reads the last character of a UTF-8 text file.
    :param filename: The path to the text file to read
    :param ignore_newlines: Set to true, if the newline character at the end of the file should be ignored 
    :return: Returns the last UTF-8 character in the file or None, if the file is empty 
    """
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        last_char = None

        # Reads last 4 bytes, as the maximum size of an UTF-8 character is 4 bytes
        num_bytes_to_read = 4

        # If ignore_newlines is True, read two more bytes, as a newline character
        # can be up to 2 bytes (eg. \r\n)
        # and we might have a newline character at the end of file
        # or size bytes, if file's size is less than 4 bytes
        if ignore_newlines:
            num_bytes_to_read += 2

        size = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size
        f.seek(-min(num_bytes_to_read, size), os.SEEK_END)
        last_bytes = f.read()

        # Find the first byte of a UTF-8 character, starting
        # from the last byte
        offset = -1
        while abs(offset) <= len(last_bytes):
            b = last_bytes[offset]
            if ignore_newlines and b in b'\r\n':
                offset -= 1
                continue
            if b & 0b10000000 == 0 or b & 0b11000000 == 0b11000000:
                # If this is first byte of a UTF8 character,
                # interpret this and all bytes after it as UTF-8
                last_char = last_bytes[offset:].decode('utf-8')
                break
            offset -= 1

        if last_char and ignore_newlines:
            last_char = last_char.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')

        return last_char
```

How it works:

- Reads only the last few bytes of a UTF-8 encoded text file in binary mode
- Iterates the bytes backwards, looking for the start of a UTF-8 character
- Once a character (different from a newline) is found, return that as the last character in the text file

Sample text file - `bg.txt`:

```
Здравей свят
```

How to use:

```
>>> get_last_utf8_char('bg.txt')
т
```

This works with both UTF-8 and ASCII encoded files.

Answer (score 0):

What i have done :

1. Opened the file.
2. Read the last line as list.
3. Converted it into string and read the last character and printed into.

   ```
   a=open('does&donts.txt','rb')
   lines = a.readlines()
   a.close()
   if lines:
       last_line = lines[-1]
   print  last_line
   b="".join(last_line)
   print b[-1:]
   ```

Hope it helps

Comment: There's no need to read the whole file just for sake of a single char, use `file.seek`.

Comment: Imagine having to load a 2GB log file in memory just to retrieve the last, for example, 20 characters.

Comment: @gabrielgarcia yes :|

Answer (score 0):

simply use this :

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    file_str = str(f.read())
    f.close()
last_chr = file_str[-1]
print(last_chr)
```

its important to read the file by "r" not "rb"

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the last character always has a byte value of 255, even though ASCII values range from 0 to 127. When I wrote a little program to discern between ASCII and binary files, I found that troublesome at first, but it's probably a convention for easier data recovery from hard drives.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Simplest thing I could come up with:

```
s="".join(list(open(rfile_directory))) 
pos=s[-1:]
```

steps:

1. opened the file
2. converted it into list
3. Joined the list to str form
4. The got the last character!

Now, if the character is wanted in int form, simply:

```
pos=int(s[-1:])
```