# numpy.savetxt() stop newline on final line

Tags: python, numpy

numpy.savetxt() seems to always put a new line on the end of files. Is there a nice way to avoid this behaviour? Substituting the new line character to something else doesn't help.

I don't think this is particular to my code, but the writing is being done like this (model is a 3D array):

```
np.savetxt(modelFile, model, delimiter=",", fmt='%.3f')
```

Comment: added the writing code

Comment: It might be worth asking _why_ it makes a difference... e.g. do you have some crucial post-processing that is choking due to the newline?

Comment: Agreeing with @mgilson on this one. However, would it be satisfactory for you to use the `newline=' '` option? This will remove all newlines including the one at the end of the file (to replace them with a space).

Comment: If it's really a problem, after writing the file, you could seek backward one byte in the file (`seek(-1, 2)`) and then truncate...

Comment: This is a valid question. I ran into the problem when writing a unit test. The output of savetxt did not match the expected output due to the trailing newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure *why* it matters, or if there is a way to prevent it on the numpy side (I didn't see anything in the docs...) but you can probably seek back in the file after writing and then truncate.  e.g.

```
NEWLINE_SIZE_IN_BYTES = -1  # -2 on Windows?
with open('data.dat', 'w') as fout:
    np.savetxt(fout, model, delimiter=",", fmt='%.3f')
    fout.seek(NEWLINE_SIZE_IN_BYTES, 2)
    fout.truncate()
```

Note: to seek backwards, the byte-size must be negative

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get 'UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero end-relative seeks'

Answer (score 3):

### The solution

To answer the question: **There is a nice way to avoid this behaviour**, althought it depends on your meaning of niceness. Basically, what you have to do is to wrap the `numpy.savetxt` function into another function or just use the chunk of code showed here wherever you need.

What I've done is to mix some of [@mgilson's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28493155/6304064) with [code provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533391/seeking-from-end-of-file-throwing-unsupported-exception/51131242#51131242) in an answer to another similar question. To make it short, a code saving a file using `numpy.savetxt` and eliminating the last line would be the next:

```py
import os

with open('some_array.txt', 'w') as fout:
    NEWLINE_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 1 # 2 on Windows?
    np.savetxt(fout, some_array) # Use np.savetxt.
    fout.seek(0, os.SEEK_END) # Go to the end of the file.
    # Go backwards one byte from the end of the file.
    fout.seek(fout.tell() - NEWLINE_SIZE_IN_BYTES, os.SEEK_SET)
    fout.truncate() # Truncate the file to this point.
```

The definitions of `os.SEEK_END` and `os.SEEK_SET` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.SEEK_SET). Although they are just 2 and 0 respectively.

### The logic behind the code

Some things to note here:

- The file is opened in **text** mode, not in **binary mode**. This is important as the writing and reading from a file in text mode is platform dependent if you don't specify the encoding (which we don't usually do as in the two answers provided to this question). The newline character for example is reading differently in Windows or Linux. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

  > Normally, files are opened in text mode, that means, you read and write strings from and to the file, which are encoded in a specific encoding. If encoding is not specified, the default is platform dependent (see [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)). (...)
  >   
  >   (...) In text mode, the default when reading is to convert platform-specific line endings (`\n` on Unix, `\r\n` on Windows) to just `\n`. When writing in text mode, the default is to convert occurrences of `\n` back to platform-specific line endings.
- In the next line of code, `fout.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)`, we set the current position of the file to the end of the file (see the reference for [seek()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/seek.html)). This is the only legal operation from the end of the file in *text* mode as I will cite later in this text.
- Then, in the line `fout.seek(fout.tell() - NEWLINE_SIZE_IN_BYTES, os.SEEK_SET)` we are just telling Python:

  - Set the current position backwards 1 byte from the current position: `fout.tell() - NEWLINE_SIZE_IN_BYTES`. Where `tell()` just returns the current position as you can see in the [reference](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/tell.html).
  - Starting from the beginning of the file `os.SEEK_SET`.
- The reason to do it in this way is that in the `seek()` method only offsets returned by `tell()` are legal, as it says in the [`seek()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/seek.html) documentation:

  > If the file is opened in text mode (without ‘`b`’), only offsets returned by `tell()` are legal. Use of other offsets causes undefined behavior.
- Finally, as it may be obvious by now the `truncate()` method only cuts the file up to the current position.

### Another way in binary mode

I must declare **I'm not pretty sure by now whether doing this in text mode is better than in binary mode** although the other answers made me think so, see the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533391/seeking-from-end-of-file-throwing-unsupported-exception).

Following [@mgilson's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28493155/6304064), we just need to open the file in binary mode. The modified working code is:

```py
NEWLINE_SIZE_IN_BYTES = -1  # -2 on Windows?
with open('data.dat', 'wb') as fout:  # Note 'wb' instead of 'w'
    np.savetxt(fout, model, delimiter=",", fmt='%.3f')
    fout.seek(NEWLINE_SIZE_IN_BYTES, 2)
    fout.truncate()
```

Both of these ways work for me in versions of Python > `3.2`.