# Check if the very last element of a list matches a string of choice

Tags: python, list, text

This sounds like it has been asked before but I cannot find anything that helps me.

My code is:

```
with open('file directory', 'r') as file:
data = []

for line in file:

    for word in line.split():
        data.append(str(word))
        last_word = str(data[-1])
        if last_word == "bobby":
            print("yes")
        else:print("no")
```

I want to know if the last element of the text file which I turned into a list matches a string, for example "bobby". Instead, what I get is basically a counter of how many times bobby was mentioned in the list.

Terminal:

```
yes
yes
yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look for the last word of each line, this works.

```py
with open('asdf.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.split()
        try:
            if words[-1] == "bobby":
                print("yes")
            else:
                print("no")
        except:
            # blank line
            pass
```

Comment: This worked to check every single line perfectly! I only need the very last line but this was very helpful

Comment: If you just want to look at the last line, you could use some of the code in the other answers. Keep in mind there are performance tradeoffs at play here. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278929/4476484 and note that reading the whole file with `readlines` would probably not be recommended for a very large file. Also, when using `file.readlines()[-1]`, you may run into an issue if the last line of the file is blank. Based on your application, you may want to ignore any potential last blank lines or you may not. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```py
with open('file directory', 'r') as file:
     last_line = f.readlines()[-1]
     print("yes" if last_line == "bobby" else "no")
```

or if you want to be short and cryptic:

```py
with open('file directory', 'r') as file:
     print("yes" if f.readlines()[-1] == "bobby" else "no")
```

Comment: ternary operators don't work in python. use `print("yes" if f.readlines()[-1] == "bobby" else "no")` also this only checks if the last line is bobby not the last element

Comment: @Jab that's what happens when you answer a question during a meeting and your boss suddenly starts talking to you. Thanks.

Comment: lol it happens. although your edit is still not correct.

Comment: I fixed it for ya

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping the file just turn it into a list and grab the last element. You're very close just the loop is unnecessary:

```py
with open('file directory', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    last_word = data[-1].split()[-1]
    if last_word == "bobby":
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

Comment: Would I not need to split all the words and lines from the text file though? I only want to check the last word

Comment: @RrezonBeqiri Thanks! fixed by adding split to the slice. should work

Comment: What is split supposed to be on the mapping line?

Comment: I think the split function needs 2 arguments because I'm getting " split() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'" as an error now

Comment: It should be `data[-1].split()`, not `split(data[-1])`, but keep in mind you will still have an error if the last line is blank.

Comment: Im not getting any errors but it also prints "no" when the last line is bobby and even though if i print last_word it literally says "['bobby']"