# How to read the first letter from the last line in a txt file in python

Tags: python

Can someone please show me how I can  read the first letter from the last line in a txt file in python. Sorry if the question is a little bit confusing this is my first question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution, although maybe not the best since it is not memory efficient since it reads all the contents of a text file. Reverse reading is probably too complex for what you are asking for.

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(list(f)[-1][0])
```

Comment: Calling `readlines` is unnecessary, `list(f)` will return the lines as a list as well.

Comment: True, thanks for the suggestion, will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
file_obj = open('myfile.txt')
the_text = file_obj.read()
*_, last_line = text.rsplit('\n', maxsplit=1)
first_char = last_line[0]
```

Comment: Reading the whole file just to split it is unnecessary. Using`file.readlines()` or `list(file)` is much easier.

Comment: Both suggestions will create N lines where only one is needed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to accessing the last line of a file, though takes O(n) time, is using a basic for loop:

```
file = open("script.txt", "r")
last = ""
for line in file:
  last = line
print(last[0])
```

Comment: I think using `file.readlines()[-1]`  as  @MySlav did, is preferable to looping over the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Small file solution. This opens the file, and iterates through lines until the file is completely iterated through.

```py
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        pass
    last_line_char = line[0]
```

Large file solution (also much faster). This takes advantage of the [`os.seek()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/seek.html) module.

```py
import os

with open('filename.txt', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
    while f.read(1) != b'\n':
        f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
    last_line = f.readline().decode()
    last_line_char = last_line[0]
```

Code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278929/5763413)