# Why does my save continue adding the same thing?

Tags: python, arrays

I have this example array

```
endings = ["Example1","Example2"]
```

This is my save code

```
reader = open("e_save.txt","r")
  append = open("e_save.txt","a")
  for i in endings:
    print(i)
    if i not in reader.read():
      append.write(os.linesep)
      append.write(i)
  print(reader)
```

If I run it multiple times I get outcomes like this:
Example1
Example2
Example2
Example2
It just adds more and more however the first one works perfectly.
Anyone knows a fix?

Comment: read mode `'a'` is for append. use read mode `'w'`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the file mode of `open("e_save.txt","a")`. Try using `open("e_save.txt","w")`.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files for more details.
Modes description: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

```
'r' open for reading (default)

'w' open for writing, truncating the file first

'x' open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists

'a' open for writing, appending to the end of file if it exists

'b' binary mode

't' text mode (default)

'+' open for updating (reading and writing)
```

Comment: Dzięki Łukasz pomogło mi

Answer (score 0):

Opening the file with the option a means anything you write gets added to the end of the file, try it like this

```
open("e_save.txt","w")
```

IF you do want to append to the file, try checking with the last line, you can refer here to [get the last line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46258499/12161328)

edit: you don't need the reader, you can read with append