# How to delete a symbol from file by its position

Tags: python, file, io, char

I need to delete a symbol from txt file by its position in file. For example, there is a text file `sample.txt`:

```
Hello, world!
Abcdef
hello
world
```

and I need to delete a character `,` that is located on the sixth position: `pos = 6`

I tried to use this code:

```py
pos = 6

with open('sample.txt', 'r+') as f:
    f.seek(pos - 1) # move to the position before ,
    print(f.read(1)) # print the , character
    f.seek(pos - 1) # return back to the position before ,
    f.write('\r')
    f.close()
```

This prints `,`, like I expected but file now looks like this:

```
Hello
 world!
Abcdef
hello
world
```

So my code replaced the `,` character with a new line symbol `\n`, instead of carriage return symbol `\r`.

UPD:

My solution replaces the `,` symbol with symbol with ASCII code 13 (0D), that doesn't solve my problem:

[image: gggg]

Comment: I get an error from `f.seek(-1, 1)` if the file isn't opened in binary mode.

Comment: And then it requires calling that I write a byte string, not a regular string.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001901/unsupportedoperation-cant-do-nonzero-cur-relative-seeks-python

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited this like `f.seek(pos - 1)`, and now it should work

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. What OS are you on?

Comment: It might just be that the way you're viewing the file shows a CR as a newline. Try viewing the file with a hex editor.

Comment: I used windows when did it, an I use a VSCode viewer of files

Comment: I suspect VSCode is translating CR to newline.

Comment: In a hex editor it shows like 0D and so my solution doesn't solve my problem because it doesn't remove the symbol, and just replace it with symbol with ASCII code 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode is showing the CR as a newline.

To remove it entirely, don't overwrite it with a single character. Read the rest of the file into a variable, seek back to the position, then overwrite from the variable.

```
pos = 6

with open('sample.txt', 'r+') as f:
    f.seek(pos - 1) # move to the position before ,
    print(f.read(1)) # print the , character
    rest = f.read() # read the rest of the file
    f.seek(pos - 1) # return back to the position before ,
    f.write(rest)
    f.truncate() # adjust the end of the file
```

BTW, you don't need `f.close()`, that's done automatically when you use `with`.