# Seek function Python

Tags: python

When I use the seek function, I am unable to set the whence parameter to 1. After some searching I found that I need to include a "byte--like object" so that I can set the whence parameter to 1. What does this entail, and do I always need a bytes-like object so that I can set the whence to 1 and have the offset starting from the current index position in a file?

Comment: Yes you are correct. This answer explains in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21533561/152016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `open` file in text mode, the file-like object it returns is [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) (derived from [`io._TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase)). Their [`seek()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek) with regard to `whence` works as follows:

> The default value for whence is SEEK_SET.
>
> `SEEK_SET` or `0`: seek from the start of the stream (the default); offset must either be a number returned by [`TextIOBase.tell()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell), or zero. Any other offset value produces undefined behaviour.
>
> `SEEK_CUR` or `1`: “seek” to the current position; offset must be zero, which is a no-operation (all other values are unsupported).
>
> `SEEK_END` or `2`: seek to the end of the stream; offset must be zero (all other values are unsupported).

I.e. you can use `whence` values of `1` and `2` only with `offset` of `0`.