# How to add a string behind previous line in txt by python?

Tags: python

I want to add a new string to the previous one like, I have some text in the file,

```
1
2
3
```

Now I want to add a new string behind the last sentence,not a new line

```
1
2
3hello
```

and the code like that,

```
file_convt = open("test.txt", "w")
for i in range(0, 3):
    file_convt.write(str(i) + "\n")
file_convt.write("hello")
file_convt.close()
```

The loop function is complex actually and I cannot change it, is there some better way can add a new line behind the last sentence?
I only know,

```
with open(filepath, "w") as fp:
    for line in lines:
        print(line + "#", file=fp)
```

However, my file is large and I am afraid to read it all in everytime..

Comment: 'I want to add a new string to the previous one' --- can you be more clear?

Comment: What if you view it as adding a newline to every line except the first one?

Comment: do you mean you have some existing unchangable python code(that's writting file), or you have one existing file and want to some operations?

Comment: @Chris that's the problem, I don't know where it happened about adding "hello"

Comment: @LeiYang the first one

Comment: @LeiYang if I have a existing file, and its strucute like "1 /n 2 /n 3 /n hello /n" is there some way can remove "hello" behind “3"?

Comment: i'd use regex replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> seek() method In Python,
>
> seek() function is used to change the
> position of the File Handle to a given specific position. File handle
> is like a cursor, which defines from where the data has to be read or
> written in the file.

Please visit [GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-seek-function/) site for more information regarding seek method.

When I tried to move the cursor to the end of the text file I got exception `UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero end-relative seeks`
so I have to seek only from the beggining of file.

> text files do not have a 1-to-1 correspondence between encoded bytes
> and the characters they represent, so seek can't tell where to jump to
> in the file to move by a certain number of characters.

above quote from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533391/seeking-from-end-of-file-throwing-unsupported-exception) site of stack overflow.

This might not be complete solution but it works and hope it might give you some help so you could use it to solve the problem.

`os.stat` is used to get the file **size**. After knowing to file size we can use `seek` method to go to appropriate position can modify the file efficiently.

```
import sys,random, os
file_convt = open("test.txt", "w")
for i in range(0, 3):
    file_convt.write(str(i+1) + "\n")
file_convt.close()

stats = os.stat('test.txt')
#print(stats.st_size)

with open("test.txt", "r+")as f:
    f.seek(stats.st_size-1,0) #now our cursor is after 3 and here we can write hello
    f.write("hello\n")
```

### Output:

```
$ cat test.txt 
1
2
3hello
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the `end` argument to `print` to avoid a newline being printed. We only prepend a newline after the first line is printed.

```
lines = ['1', '2', '3']
prepend = ''

for line in lines:
    print(f"{prepend}{line}", end='')
    prepend = "\n"

print("hello", end='')
```