# Why are non-zero non-absolute seeks not supported in python?

Tags: python, file-handling

According to [the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek),

> - SEEK_SET or `0`: seek from the start of the stream (the default); offset must either be a number returned by `TextIOBase.tell()`, or zero. Any other offset value produces undefined behaviour.
> - SEEK_CUR or `1`: “seek” to the current position; offset must be zero, which is a nooperation (all other values are unsupported).
> - SEEK_END or `2`: seek to the end of the stream; offset must be zero (all other values are unsupported).

For `SEEK_END` and `SEEK_CUR`, why is only 0 offset supported?
Has it simply not been implemented yet/does it need a PEP?
Is this by design? If so, why?

Is there a workaround with acceptable performance (for files with UTF-8, without using undefined behavior)?
All the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533391/seeking-from-end-of-file-throwing-unsupported-except) either use undefined behavior or don't handle files with UTF-8.

Comment: The question you linked explains the problem for utf-8 text pretty well: UTF-8 backward seeking is very tricky. You cannot really do it in text mode, but if you want - use binary mode and handle decoding manually.

Comment: You could work with binary files, after seek check if the byte referred by the file pointer is in a multibyte character and, if so, adjust the pointer accordingly.

Comment: You're asking too many different questions at once here. Do you want an answer to the "Why" or the "Is there a workaround"? Pick one.