# Extract only the last line using read() function

Tags: python, line, readlines

I'm using the following code for some text analysis (I've more code for the analysis):

```
with open(os.path.join(root, file)) as auto:
    a = auto.read(50000)
    for line in auto:
      print(line)
```

My question is: how can I print only the last line of the file?

I try this approach but I don't think it is a good option since it doesn't return any message:

```
with open(os.path.join(root, file)) as auto:
            a = auto.read(50000)
            lines = a.readlines()
            last_line = lines[-1]
            for line in auto:
                print(last_line)
```

How can I print the last line of the file using auto.read()?

Thanks

Comment: you can count file lines (wc -l file) and seek at last line number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to get first and last line of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346430/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-first-and-last-line-of-a-text-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

**list.txt**:

```
sdfs
sdfs
fg34
345
gn
4564
```

**Hence**:

```
with open('list.txt') as fileObj:
    print(list(fileObj)[-1])
```

Using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path
print(Path('list.txt').read_text().splitlines()[-1])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
4564
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that

> I try this approach but I don't think it is a good option since it doesn't return any message:

and then asked for a technique using `read()`.  However, I think your approach is reasonable and it does work (though I suspect that the file you're reading has a blank line as the last line of the file).  For example, this does indeed print the last line of the file:

```
import os
with open('test.py') as auto:
    lines = auto.readlines()
    last_line = lines[-1]
    print(last_line)
```