# Python f.seek caused OSError [Errno 22] if manually edit the text file but no error if program output to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I am trying to get last line from a text file, which I used the solution from
[What is the most efficient way to get first and last line of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346430/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-first-and-last-line-of-a-text-file)

```
def read_last_line(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        first = f.readline()
        if f.read(1) == '':
            return first
        f.seek(-2, 2)  # Jump to the second last byte.
        while f.read(1) != b"\n":  # Until EOL is found...
            f.seek(-2, 1)  # ...jump back the read byte plus one more.
        last = f.readline()  # Read last line.
        return last.decode('ascii')
```

It managed to get the last line of the text file successfully if the file is modified by another script/program, but when I modify the text file using `Notepad++` the exact same modification as another script/program, it will throw the following exception:

```
in read_last_line
    f.seek(-2, 2)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

What I am trying to do is, I used `watchdog` to check if there's file changes, and on modify I will call `read_last_line` on the modified file.

Sample file

```
11/26/2020 2:05:12 PM Time Updated: +2ms            Regular Update
11/26/2020 2:06:13 PM Time Updated: +4ms            Regular Update
11/26/2020 2:07:13 PM Time Updated: +1ms            Regular Update
```

How I am calling the function:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import ntpath

class FileEventHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, filetowatch):
        self.file = filetowatch
    
    def on_modified(self, event):
        modified_file = ntpath.basename(event.src_path)
        if modified_file == self.file:
            read_last_line(event.src_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = FileEventHandler("sample.txt")
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='C:/Program Files (x86)/SomeTime', recursive=False)
    observer.start()
```

May I know if anyone know what is causing the error?

Platform: Windows 10, Python 3.7.4

**UPDATE - ANSWER**

So the error was because of `fread(1) == ''` which was fixed using [falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225682/falsetru)'s solution.

The reason why it is not performing the way I expected was because text editor **deletes** the sample file and create a file using the same file name, therefore `fread(1)==''` was triggered (which throws) and using script/program to modify the sample file did not throw simply because I did not delete the file.

Comment: Is it possible that Notepad++ is deleting the file when you save and creating another one with the same name?

Comment: @MarkRansom it also crashed using sublime and notepad as well.. I will add in code to check if file deletion is triggered.

Comment: @MarkRansom indeed, text editor is deleting my file, which caused it to throw error when I do `f.read(1) == ''` - not using binary string caused the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only a single (with / without trailing newline), while loop condition will never be met.

That cause `f.seek(-2, 1)` to try to seek to negative file position which causes the error.

Guard such case (prevent trying to seek beyond the file beginning), using [`.tell()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.tell) which let you know current file position:

```py
        while f.tell() >= 1 and f.read(1) != b"\n":
```

or you can use `seek(..)` return value:

```py
        while f.read(1) != b"\n":
            if f.seek(-2, 1) == 0:
                break  # prevent going beyond file beginning.
```

**UPDATE**

In binary mode `<io object>.read()` return bytes object. In `if` condition, the code is comparing the bytes object with a string `''`; which will always fail because of type difference.
Changing to compare with bytes literal will fix the issue.

```py
        if f.read(1) == b'':
            return first
```

Comment: this is does not solve the issue..it did not throw error because the file position is wrong. the exact same modification i made and output to the file using a script will not cause an error and will return the correct last line.

Comment: @Potatoismyname, https://asciinema.org/a/RYBfGjob1mJuxIVixVfE208Wa

Comment: thanks for the video, but i have tried both solution you've provided, it is still the same issue. No error if it's modified through script/program/command prompt  (I am using Windows) but error when it's modified through Notepad++/sublime/notepad ..

Comment: @Potatoismyname, Could you provide a file you used. And code lines that call the function `read_last_line`?

Comment: I have updated the question with a sample file. I just copy and paste the same line to the bottom of the file using text editor.

Comment: @Potatoismyname, I updated the answer. In short, replace `''` with `b''`.

Comment: I have also added the code snippet that i am calling `read_last_line` with.

Comment: I have added `b''` but it does not solve the issue.

Comment: @Potatoismyname, Could you add `print(repr(first_line), f.tell())` line before `f.seek(-2, 2)` line and let me know the output?

Comment: @Potatoismyname, As Mark Ransom commented, it could be possible notepad delete/modify while `read_last_line`. Try `time.sleep(0.5)` at the first line of `read_last_line`.

Comment: i am sorry, the `b''` fixed the error, but do you know why appending a line at the bottom of the file using text editor will result in null ?

Comment: @Potatoismyname, What do you mean by `null`? empty string?

Comment: yes, i append the line in sample.txt and `f.read(1) == b''` returns true. Why does it not get the last line that i appended? but using program to append to sample.txt is does not have such issue

Comment: @Potatoismyname, `f.read(1) == b''` means there's nothing to read more. IOW, There's only single line (with or without newline) or there's no line at all (0 byte file)

Comment: thank you so much for explaining and answering me!!

Comment: @Potatoismyname, You're welcome. Happy programming!